# Info Logging Disabled in SpringApplicationRunListener.starting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was working on creating a new `SpringApplicationRunListener` and tried to insert some logging into the starting method.  The logging was at `INFO` level.  However, the logging would not show at the console.  All of my other logging for the class works as expected thus far.  The relevant parts of my project follow:

Build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
}

group 'org.cspringer'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
}
```

Custom SpringApplicationRunListener

```
public class CustomSpringApplicationRunListener implements SpringApplicationRunListener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomSpringApplicationRunListener.class);

    public CustomSpringApplicationRunListener(SpringApplication springApplication, String... args) {
        log.info("inside ctor");
    }

    @Override
    public void starting() {
        System.out.println("<sout> inside starting");
        System.out.println("is info logging enabled: " + log.isInfoEnabled());
        log.info("inside starting");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextPrepared(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        log.info("inside contextPrepared");
    }
}
```

Simple class with main method

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class Example {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Example.class);

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }
}
```

Logging configuration in application.properties

```
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.cspringer=INFO
```

Required spring factory configuration in META-INF/spring.factories

```
# example application run listener
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener=\
org.cspringer.springboot.sandbox.listeners.CustomSpringApplicationRunListener
```

And finally the output

```
C:\Users\Chris\IdeaProjects\spring-boot-sandbox>java -jar build\libs\spring-boot-sandbox-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
17:36:35.042 [main] INFO org.cspringer.springboot.sandbox.listeners.CustomSpringApplicationRunListener - inside ctor
<sout> inside starting
is info logging enabled: false

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2020-04-12 17:36:35.271  INFO 16256 --- [           main] s.s.l.CustomSpringApplicationRunListener : inside contextPrepared
2020-04-12 17:36:35.273  INFO 16256 --- [           main] o.cspringer.springboot.sandbox.Example   : Starting Example on ChrisPC with PID 16256 (C:\Users\Chris\IdeaProjects\spring-boot-sandbox\build\libs\spring-boot-sandbox-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar started by Chris in C:\Users\Chris\IdeaProjects\spring-boot-sandbox)
2020-04-12 17:36:35.274  INFO 16256 --- [           main] o.cspringer.springboot.sandbox.Example   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-12 17:36:35.868  INFO 16256 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-04-12 17:36:35.875  INFO 16256 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-04-12 17:36:35.875  INFO 16256 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2020-04-12 17:36:35.913  INFO 16256 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-04-12 17:36:35.913  INFO 16256 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 607 ms
2020-04-12 17:36:36.012  INFO 16256 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-12 17:36:36.140  INFO 16256 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-04-12 17:36:36.142  INFO 16256 --- [           main] o.cspringer.springboot.sandbox.Example   : Started Example in 1.1 seconds (JVM running for 1.341)
```

Notice that the logging using the `Logger` implementation does not display but the calls to `System.out.println` do, in fact, show up.  Also notice that the `log.isInfoEnabled()` call returns false.  I've searched the Spring source code to see if somehow `SpringApplication` is disabling logging but I can't find anything.  I'm at a loss as to how `INFO` logging is magically being turned off and then turned back on here.

Comment: I've found that there are exactly two `SpringApplicationRunListener` implementations on the classpath: my custom listener and an instance of `EventPublishingRunListener`.  If I implement the `Ordered` interface on my custom listener and set it to a slightly higher priority than that of the `EventPublishingRunListener` to force it to happen first, I get the expected logging.  From this, I am making the assumption that the multicasting of the `EventPublishingRunListener` is somehow causing an event in another thread that is impacting logging.

Comment: I suspect `LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent`'s call to `loggingSystem.beforeInitialize` may be the source of my problems.  From looking at the code, this listener should be executing in a separate thread.  It looks like the underlying `Slf4JLoggingSystem` temporarily removes any installed `Slf4JBridgeHandler` before subsequently re-installing it.  I'm not sure why this is necessary but it's the only theory I've got so far.  This can be seen in `Slf4JLoggingSystem.removeJDKLoggingBridgeHandler`.  It seems to me this should be a synchronous operation on the main thread.